# Most performant way to execute JS within a webpage in Ruby (HtmlUnit, Celerity, PhantomJS, CasperJS ...)

Tags: javascript, jruby, capybara, phantomjs, casperjs

What's the most performant way to execute JS directly after a HTTP request in JRuby? I know about all the test frameworks like HtmlUnit, Celerity, Capybara + PhantomJS == Poltergeist, CasperJS etc. but they're still test frameworks.

What I need is a simple way to execute all JS code which is included in HTML after fetching the URL e.g. by Net::Http.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it goes with out saying: **DON'T DO THIS IN PRODUCTION!**

Executing some script that's been pulled from *somewhere* on the internet is a recipe for disaster. If you're using it as part of your testing infrastructure, it may be of some use but I'd guess that there's a simpler way to solve your problem.

To answer the more general question, here's how you'd initialize a JavaScript engine bundled with JDK 1.6+ (effectively a cut down version of Rhino, although this will change in Java 8 probably):

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager
import javax.script.SimpleBindings

manager = ScriptEngineManager.new
engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript")

bindings = SimpleBindings.new
bindings['x'] = 1

engine.eval("print(x)", bindings)
```

Getting your engine to evaluate any dependencies like jQuery is left as an exercise to the user. Have a look at the [javax.script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html) JavaDoc.

If you need more control over the evaluation environment you'll have to use [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Rhino) directly, or wait for [Nashorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_%28JavaScript_engine%29)...